# ContentPresenter not showing Usercontrol, how come?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles

I have a `ListBox` that displays a number of usercontrols that are bound to my questions.  This is working fine, however I don't want each of the items in the `ListBox` to be selectable, as such I created a blank style and applied it to the `ItemContainerStyle`. This has resulted in my content to disappear and each item is showing blank. Any ideas?

--Xaml--

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource noSelect}" Name="lbTasks" Height="180"
         BorderBrush="#E6E6E6" >
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <my:TaskQuestion Question="{Binding Test}" />
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

--Style--

```
<Style x:Key="noSelect" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2, 2, 2, 0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Am i using the content presenter incorrectly?

Tia, Kohan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set TargetType for your ControlTemplate in the Style
e. g. <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">